# R: Why does eval evaluate in parent.frame() by default?

Tags: r, scope

I was trying to evaluate some expressions in a function using `eval` but it would run into an error trying to find the objects which were defined in the function scope.

I realized that this was because `eval`'s default environment is `parent.frame()`. Is there a good reason for this? I would expect it to be the same as, say, `assign`, that is, the current environment.

Here is an example (per Gabor's request):

```
fnFoo = function() {
    # assign 10 variables
    for(i in 1:10) assign(paste('v', i, sep = ''), rnorm(10))

    # find the variables by name and evaluate them
    Map(sum, lapply(parse(text = grep('v', ls(envir = environment()), value = TRUE)), eval))
}

# test that eval is unable to find a variable  declared in the function scope
fnFoo()
```

However, changing the function to

```
fnFoo = function() {
    # assign 10 variables
    for(i in 1:10) assign(paste('v', i, sep = ''), rnorm(10))

    # find the variables by name and evaluate them
    # Map(sum, lapply(parse(text = grep('v', ls(envir = environment()), value = TRUE)), eval))
    Map(sum, lapply(parse(text = grep('v', ls(envir = environment()), value = TRUE)), function(x) eval(x, envir = environment())))
}

# now it works
fnFoo()
```

works.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide self contained code that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are being too clever with your `lapply` in conjuction with `eval`. Let's expand what is happening.

```
lapply(parse(text = grep('v', ls(envir = environment()), value = TRUE)), eval)
```

is equivalent to

```
lapply(parse(text = grep('v', ls(envir = environment()), value = TRUE)),
   function(x) eval(x))
```

However, a separate scope gets created for `function(x) eval(x)`, which no longer has `v1`, `v2`, etc. in its immediate environment. Thus, you want to tell `eval` in conjunction with `lapply` to use the correct environment:

```
lapply(parse(text = grep('v', ls(envir = environment()), value = TRUE)),
       eval, envir = environment())
```

By the way, another approach is

```
apply(sapply(grep('v', ls(envir = environment()), value = TRUE), get, envir = environment()), 1, sum)
```

Comment: Actually the example is a red herring, I know that `eval`'s default is `parent.frame()`, I just wanted an explanation why. The example is there because Gabor asked for one.

Comment: Then wouldn't the answer just be that `eval` is usually used as a "directly applied" function where parent.frame() returns the sensible environment, rather than being called when passed by name when the expected environment is not the parent.frame?

Comment: @BondedDust Not sure about the being sensible bit. Virtually every other lookup function looks in the current environment before looking upwards.